# Swift delegates isn't working

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, delegation

I'm trying to use delegates between two controllers but it doesn't work as it should be

```
protocol saveDelegate: class {
    func saveSite()
}
class AuditSiteViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: saveDelegate?

   @IBAction func saveButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("Saved")
        delegate?.saveSite()
    }
}


class AuditDetailsViewController: UIViewController,  saveDelegate {
     var mainView: AuditSiteViewController?

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mainView?.delegate = self

    }

    func saveSite() {
        print("delegated")
    }
}
```

it should print delegated but it only prints "saved"?

Comment: I'm trying to fire save function from another viewcontroller, shouldn't i use delegates? or what?

Comment: I tried to create it as an instance but i still got nothing, i was just following online resources about it to make it work so that's what i got, how can i solve this? with code if possible?

Comment: You have a debugger. A wonderful debugger. Debug!

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate, but have you debug and check that `mainView` is the correct instance?

My suggestion in this case would be to use NSNotification instead. You can add a observer in your `viewDidLoad` and post a notification on the `saveButton()`

```
class AuditDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AuditDetailsViewController.saveSite), name: "SaveSite", object: nil)
  }
}

class AuditSiteViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBAction func saveButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("SaveSite", object: nil)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there are only two reasons possible:

First:
In the moment of calling `mainView?.delegate = self` mainView is nil. Then the delegate isn't assigned. Set a breakpoint there and you will see it.

Second:
In the moment of calling `delegate?.saveSite()` the delegate is nil. That may be because your instance of AuditDetailsViewController was deinit by you or system. System removes the instance if noone holds a strong reference to it anymore. Implement the deinit method and set a breakpoint in it to see when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the mainView is nil when you set the delegate. Try to set the reference when you instantiate the detail view controller.

Anyway, maybe what you want is to delegate the saving action from the detailViewController to the AuditSiteViewController and handle in this last VC the savings.